# Update local repository folder when there are changes in remote or some files are deleted in local with Jgit library

Tags: jgit

I'm trying for a couple of days to implement something that I was expecting to be easy. Use jGit library to clone a repository to a local folder and update the local folder to be always matching the remote. I've searched all over the place for a solution but the update part does not work, no matter what (clone works fine). Below is the code I have with both the clone and the update parts (the tries at least...) Can someone guide me on what am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

```
public class JgitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        cloneRepository();
        updateRepository();
        checkRepo();
    }

    private static void cloneRepository() {
        Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
                .setURI("MY_URI")
                .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/main"))
                .setDirectory(new File("C:\\A_FOLDER"))
                .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("MYUSER", "MYPASSWORD"))
                .call();

        git = Git.open(new File("C:\\A_FOLDER"));
        StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
        config.setString("branch", "main", "merge", "refs/heads/main");
        config.setString("branch", "main", "remote", "origin");
        config.setString("remote", "origin", "fetch", "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*");
        config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", "https://MYUSER@bitbucket.org/MYUSER/jGitTest.git");
        config.save();
    }

    private static void checkRepo() {
        Git git = Git.open(new File("C:\\A_FOLDER));
        FetchResult result = git.fetch()
                .setRemote("origin")
                .setRefSpecs("refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main")
                .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("MYUSER", "MYPASSWORD"))
                .call();
    }

    private static void updateRepository() {
        try {
            Repository localRepo = new FileRepository("C:\\A_FOLDER" + "/.git");
            Git git = new Git(localRepo);
            CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("MYUSER", "MYPASSWORD");

            git.fetch().setCredentialsProvider(cp).setForceUpdate(true).call();

            git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(cp).setRebase(true).call();
            git.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is bit ambiguous. There are two types of updates on the any repo once its cloned. If you are talking in terms of getting latest changes like you are working on it, then you usually Pull or Fetch the latest changes.

If you are referring to backup of repositories so they can always contain the latest replica then you can use git clone with --mirror parameter to clone the repos initially and you use git remote update to update them subsequently.

JGit is just a simple wrapper on Git Protocol, use above git commands in your logic.

Comment: I just need to get locally, what is in the remote when I click a button in my app, for example. Very simple behavior. And I want to use JGit. How can I use git protocol directly in java in this case?